# For internet explorer what should i need to use for internet explorer to disable the default drop down style of internet explorer

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
-webkit-appearance: none;
-moz-appearance: none;
appearance: none;
```

not working in internet explorer 
For internet explorer what should i need to use for internet explorer to disable the default drop down style of internet explorer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike other browsers, Internet Explorer will not fully disable a  element’s style when you use the CSS3 appearance property. To hide the dropdown’s arrow, use the following CSS line:

select::-ms-expand { display: none; }

check below example for IE Browser

http://jsbin.com/fifawu/3/edit?html,output

Comment: Thanks pavan and sorry Dileep pavan explained me in Good way...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    .classname:: -ms-expand{
       display: none;
     }
```

Comment: no it is not working

Comment: Just i used this it is working but i con't understand how can i only disable the icon of select below is my css and js code 

html[data-useragent*='MSIE 10.0'] .select-style > select { /*appearance: none;*/ display:none; } 
<script type="text/javascript"> var doc = document.documentElement; doc.setAttribute('data-useragent', navigator.userAgent); </script> –